# Parse HTML on nodejs app

Tags: node.js

I have a node js app that gets me a another site's html source into a variable (result.body)

I want to get the value of an input tag.

```
<input type="hidden" id="session" value="xxxxxxx">
```

I have tried using jsdom like this:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(result.body);

console.log("dom ********************");
console.log(dom);
var session  = dom.window.document.getElementById('#session').value;
```

I get the following in console:

```
dom ********************
JSDOM {}
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by installing Cheerio.

Answer (score 0):

`var session  = dom.window.document.querySelector('#session').value;` instead